# how to prioritise between home and work network connections

Tags: networking, vpn

I work at home and have a vpn and lan connection

Vpn is ok for work related bits but for some reason browsing the internet is very slow. If i disconnect the vpn then the problem goes away. Can I set my laptop to browse via the lan connection whilst still also using the vpn connection to remain on the work network?

Comment: If your workplace uses a separate IP range from what you have at home, it might be possible to set up a route that covers the work network going through the VPN, and go directly to your normal default gateway in all other cases. Can you tell us a little more about the IP layout (what subnets are in use on your home network and at work), what OS you are using (the answers will be quite different from Windows 8 to Linux) and how you are establishing the VPN connection itself?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your vpn connection you have under networking a tcp/ip4 connection line. Click on that and choose properties button. Then click advanced. Deselect "use default gateway on remote network" and click ok. (4x)

If that option is selected you're effectively using the internet connection via your vpn connection and not your own direct connection. So after desecting it you wil only use your vpn if some program uses its ip directly and all your own internet traffic wil use your own internet connection.